# Pure javascript: Set border for draggable elements

Tags: javascript, html

Good day,

Learning Javascript and trying to make draggable elements inside a container.

How to set the draggable border so that elements won't be able to move outside it ?
Right now i have a problem when you drag something to the bottom or right border the element moves outside the container.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLnz68nz/4/)

my HTML looks like this :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="comboCon1"></div>
    <div id="comboCon2"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the function where i get all positions and call the `onmousemove` Event :

```
function OnMouseClickDown(event) {

    var target; // -> Element that triggered the event

    if (event.target != null) { // -> If Browser is IE than use 'srcElement'

        target = event.target;
    } else {
        target = event.srcElement;
    }

    //  Check which button was clicked and if element has class 'draggable'
    if ((event.button == 1 || event.button == 0) && target.className == "draggable") {

        // Current Mouse position
        startX = event.clientX;
        startY = event.clientY;

        // Current Element position
        offsetX = ExtractNumber(target.style.left); // -> Convert to INT
        offsetY = ExtractNumber(target.style.top);

        // Border ( Div Container ) 

        minBoundX = target.parentNode.offsetLeft; // Minimal -> Top Position.
        minBoundY = target.parentNode.offsetTop;

        maxBoundX = minBoundX + target.parentNode.offsetWidth - target.offsetWidth; // Maximal.
        maxBoundY = minBoundY + target.parentNode.offsetHeight - target.offsetHeight;



        oldZIndex = target.style.zIndex;
        target.style.zIndex = 10; // -> Move element infront of others

        dragElement = target; // -> Pass to onMouseMove

        document.onmousemove = OnMouseMove; // -> Begin drag.

        document.body.focus() // -> Cancel selections

        document.onselectstart = function () { return false }; // -> Cancel selection in IE.
    }
}
```

And here is `onmousemove` Event :

```
function OnMouseMove(event) {

   dragElement.style.left = Math.max(minBoundX, Math.min(offsetX + event.clientX - startX, maxBoundX)) + "px";
   dragElement.style.top = Math.max(minBoundY, Math.min(offsetY + event.clientY - startY, maxBoundY)) + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a little change in css for solve this problem, because you are usingf position "relative" the offset of container is given to the child is draged
so in my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tLnz68nz/4/)  put drag element in position absolute, and change offsetWidth for clientWidth and seems works ( horizontal):

```
// Draggable Div 1
    document.getElementById("comboCon1").style.position = "relative"; // -> Add position relative
    document.getElementById("comboCon1").style.width = "151px";
    document.getElementById("comboCon1").style.height = "10px";
    document.getElementById("comboCon1").setAttribute("class", "draggable");

    document.getElementById("comboCon1").style.border = "1px solid black";
    document.getElementById("comboCon1").style.padding = "0px";


    // Draggable Div 2
    document.getElementById("comboCon2").style.position = "relative";
    document.getElementById("comboCon2").style.width = "151px";
    document.getElementById("comboCon2").setAttribute("class", "draggable");

    document.getElementById("comboCon2").style.border = "1px solid black";
    document.getElementById("comboCon2").style.padding = "10px";


    // Container
    document.getElementById("container").style.border = "1px solid black"; 
    document.getElementById("container").style.width = "500px";
    document.getElementById("container").style.height = "500px";

    //////////////////////
    // Begin Drag events
    //////////////////////

    var startX = 0; //-> Mouse position.
    var startY = 0;

    var offsetX = 0; // -> Element position
    var offsetY = 0;

    var minBoundX = 0; // -> Top Drag Position ( Minimum )
    var minBoundY = 0;

    var maxBoundX = 0; // -> Bottom Drag Position ( Maximum )
    var maxBoundY = 0;

    var dragElement; // -> Pass the target to OnMouseMove Event

    var oldZIndex = 0; // -> Increase Z-Index while drag

    // 1)
    initDragDrop(); // -> initialize 2 Events.

    function initDragDrop() {
        document.onmousedown = OnMouseClickDown;
        document.onmouseup = OnMouseClickUp;
    }

    // 2) Click on Element
    function OnMouseClickDown(event) {

        var target; // -> Element that triggered the event

        if (event.target != null) { // -> If Browser is IE than use 'srcElement'

            target = event.target;
        } else {
            target = event.srcElement;
        }

        //  Check which button was clicked and if element has class 'draggable'
        if ((event.button == 1 || event.button == 0) && target.className == "draggable") {

            // Current Mouse position
            startX = event.clientX;
            startY = event.clientY;

            // Current Element position
            offsetX = ExtractNumber(target.style.left); // -> Convert to INT

            offsetY = ExtractNumber(target.style.top);

            // Border ( Div Container ) 

            minBoundX = target.parentNode.offsetLeft; // Minimal -> Top Position.
            console.log(target.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect(), target)
            minBoundY = target.parentNode.offsetTop;

            maxBoundX = minBoundX + target.parentNode.clientWidth - target.clientWidth; // Maximal.
            console.log(maxBoundX, target.parentNode.clientWidth, target.clientWidth);
            maxBoundY = minBoundY + target.parentNode.offsetHeight - target.offsetHeight;



            oldZIndex = target.style.zIndex;
            target.style.zIndex = 10; // -> Move element infront of others
            target.style.position = 'absolute'

            dragElement = target; // -> Pass to onMouseMove

            document.onmousemove = OnMouseMove; // -> Begin drag.

            document.body.focus() // -> Cancel selections

            document.onselectstart = function () { return false }; // -> Cancel selection in IE.
        }
    }

    // 3) Convert current Element position in INT
    function ExtractNumber(value) {

        var number = parseInt(value);

        if (number == null || isNaN(number)) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return number;
        }
    }

    // 4) Drag
    function OnMouseMove(event) {

       dragElement.style.left = Math.max(minBoundX, Math.min(offsetX + event.clientX - startX, maxBoundX)) + "px";

       dragElement.style.top = Math.max(minBoundY, Math.min(offsetY + event.clientY - startY, maxBoundY)) + "px";
    }

    // 5) Drop
    function OnMouseClickUp(event) {
        if (dragElement != null) {

            dragElement.style.zIndex = oldZIndex; // -> set Z-index 0.

            document.onmousemove = null;
            document.onselectstart = null;

            dragElement = null; // -> No more element to drag.
        }
    }
```

Comment: A big thank you, it does work ! Now i just have to understand the difference between clientWidth and offsetWidth.

Comment: seems in your case not affect, beacause in height works fine and it not changed is used offsetWith. The different is used padding and or not to calculate the width of htmlElement