# Drag 2 Divs through the whole space of a container div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to drag 2 divs inside an bigger div. Test1 works great, but Test2 can't be dragged over Test1. The Problem is, that the value `left=0` of Test2 is set to its current relative position. So the `left=0` of Test2 is at the edge to Test1. Thats why I can't move it past (left) its original position. I need this value to be set to the `absolute` `left=0` of its parent div (`id="ganz"`), so I can drag it over Test1 through the whole parent div.
I can't figure out how to do this. Can you guys help me?

Here is the fiddle demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/pr0cz/wq9amoxd/6/

Original source of JS: [Pure javascript: Set border for draggable elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771610/pure-javascript-set-border-for-draggable-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to provide

```
document.getElementById("rechtsheader").style.position = "absolute";
```

BUT also add `left` and `top` inline to the div element. Without the inline declaring it always sets `left` and `top` back to `top:20px left:20px` because it doesn't seem to recognize the current values from the css. This is why the element jumps back to the top left corner, as in the comments of @bru17 mentioned.

```
<div id="rechtsheader" style="top:0px; left:105px;">Test2</div>
```

Snippet is updated.

Answer (score 0):

And why don't you apply `position: absolute;` from the beginning?

```
document.getElementById("rechtsheader").style.position = "absolute";
```

I have made the change directly in your codepen and it works

Comment: hm, if I do this, both divs overlap and I have to set to "rechtsheader" left:60px; that they are beside each other. If I want to drag it it now jumps back to the left top corner at first. This is not a good solution for usability. Important is that it should display besides Test1 and that this is its starting point to drag it around.